# How to typeset an inner product in Latex?

Tags: symbols

I want to write an inner product in Latex. Using the normal characters `<` and `>`, the inner product brackets end up looking more like less-than and greater-than signs. How do I typeset  more narrow brackets, like this?

[image]

Comment: You can take a look at my answer to [scaling-of-langle-and-rangle-for-large-enclosed-symbols](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389450/scaling-of-langle-and-rangle-for-large-enclosed-symbols/389474#389474), which takes into account the size of the contents, and the possibility the arguments be empty.

Answer (score 1):

`\langle` and `\rangle` do the trick.